# jQuery On Method Issue

Tags: jquery

Hi 2 all i am using jQuery .On method to append rows , when i click add row button first time it append row but when second and next time it will do nothing . I need to know why my .on method is not working 
Here is my Code

```
<div class="form">
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'productoption-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
));
?>
<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'title', array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'title'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <strong><h3>Add Product Options</h3></strong>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span-6 headrowname"><strong>Name</strong></div>
    <div class="span-4 headrowprice"><strong>Price</strong></div>
    <div class="span-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="appendrow">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="span-6">
            <input style="width:100%!important;" type="text" name="option_name" placeholder="Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="span-4 ">
            <input id="pricetext" type="text" name="option_price" placeholder="Price" required />
        </div>
        <div class="span-2"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary addrowbtn" value="Add Row" name="addrow" /> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

```
<script>

        $('.addrowbtn').on('click','', function() {
            $('.appendrow').append('<div class="row">\n\
            <div class="span-6">\n\
            <input style="width:100%!important;" type="text" name="option_name" placeholder="Name" required />\n\
            </div><div class="span-4 ">\n\
            <input id="pricetext" type="text" name="option_price" placeholder="Price" required />\n\
            </div><div class="span-2">\n\
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary addrowbtn" value="Add Row" name="addrow" />\n\
            </div>\n\
            </div>');
        });

</script>
```

Comment: [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Please don't dump all of your code, but only the minimal amount needed to understand the question. The whole top and bottom parts of your page are just noise.

Comment: I agree with @AvnerShahar-Kashtan, you only needed you `script` section and contents of `<div class="appendrow"> ... </div>` to provide necessary details for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery attaches `onclick` event only to the first instance of `.addrowbtn` but not to newly added ones since they are generated on the fly, so it ends up generating multiple non-functioning 'Add Row' buttons.

And while you can re-attach `onclick` event to those new buttons on the fly, I believe the better way to handle this is have single 'Add Row' button outside of `.appendrow` div, here is the fiddle using your code:

> http://jsfiddle.net/unez9Lrf/

Comment: $(document.body).on('click','.addrowbtn', function() {}) solve the problem

Comment: @FahadAkram, that does indeed, esp. if you need 'Add Row' button duplicated after each row. You can also narrow it down to `$('.appendrow').on('click','.addrowbtn', function() {}` so that if you need to create more `onclick` events on same page they won't conflict with one attached to whole `$(document.body)`.